# String split of IDs and concat with names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, split, concatenation

I have following tables in MySQL

Table 1:
c1     ids
A1       3|5|2
A2       1|2
A3       3
A4       1|2|3|4|5
A5       2|4|1|3

Table 2:
id    name
1     AA
2     ABERT
3     CDE
4     XXWQ
5     Y

I want to join both the tables on tb1.ids = tb2.id as Split all the id from table 1 and then replace with their names and then concatenate again.

Output

3|5|2 -> CDE|Y|ABERT
1|2 ->  AA|ABERT

I am using following code to split the string.

```
CASE WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%'THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', 1 ) ELSE tb1.ids END AS id1,
CASE WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', 2 ),'|',-1) WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', -1 )ELSE '' END AS id2,
CASE WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%|%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', 3 ),'|',-1) WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', -1 ) ELSE '' END AS id3,
CASE WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%|%|%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', 4 ),'|',-1) WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%|%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', -1 ) ELSE '' END AS id4,
CASE WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%|%|%|%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', 5 ),'|',-1) WHEN tb1.ids LIKE '%|%|%|%|%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX( `tb1.ids` , '|', -1 ) ELSE '' END AS id5
```

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column. If you do you get problems like this. Can you change your table design?

Comment: I do not have write access to that database. Actually, that column is an itinerary of multiple destinations of a particular trip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing delimited fields in a table is almost always a bad idea.

However if the field is delimited with commas then you can use the FIND_IN_SET function. If desperate you can use REPLACE to change the delimiters to commas within the FIND_IN_SET function:-

```
SELECT a.c1,
        a.ids,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.name SEPARATOR '|')
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, REPLACE(a.ids, '|', ','))
GROUP BY a.c1,
        a.ids
```

Comment: This is even better than my solution.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for fixing the typos with the commas.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you :)

Comment: @HarshRaval - To order the names use `GROUP_CONCAT(b.name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(b.id, REPLACE(a.ids, '|', ','))  SEPARATOR '|')`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the schema you can join using LIKE and combine the names with GROUP_CONCAT:

```
select t1.c1, t1.ids, group_concat(t2.name separator '|') as names
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
  on concat('|', t1.ids, '|') like concat('%|', t2.id, '|%')
group by t1.c1, t1.ids
```

Result:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ c1 ║    ids    ║        names        ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ A1 ║ 3|5|2     ║ CDE|ABERT|Y         ║
║ A2 ║ 1|2       ║ ABERT|AA            ║
║ A3 ║ 3         ║ CDE                 ║
║ A4 ║ 1|2|3|4|5 ║ CDE|Y|ABERT|AA|XXWQ ║
║ A5 ║ 2|4|1|3   ║ XXWQ|CDE|ABERT|AA   ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/XHUP28245

If you need need the names to be ordered according to `t1.ids`, one possible way is to use the LOCATE function for ORDER BY in GROUP_CONCAT:

```
select t1.c1, t1.ids, group_concat(
    t2.name
    order by locate(concat('|', t2.id, '|'), concat('|', t1.ids, '|'))
    separator '|'
) as names
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
  on concat('|', t1.ids, '|') like concat('%|', t2.id, '|%')
group by t1.c1, t1.ids
```

Result:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ c1 ║    ids    ║        names        ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ A1 ║ 3|5|2     ║ CDE|Y|ABERT         ║
║ A2 ║ 1|2       ║ AA|ABERT            ║
║ A3 ║ 3         ║ CDE                 ║
║ A4 ║ 1|2|3|4|5 ║ AA|ABERT|CDE|XXWQ|Y ║
║ A5 ║ 2|4|1|3   ║ ABERT|XXWQ|AA|CDE   ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/WIUQ61685

Comment: Why are you using group by as in if two values are same then only one record will be created as in   

A1 -> 3|2|5   
A2 -> 3|2|5

Comment: I've changed the query to somethig that makes more sense. You didn't post the exact output format in your question.

Comment: Why two same tb2.ids are giving jumbled names as in   
A1 -> 3|5|2 -> CDE|Y|ABERT    
A2 -> 3|5|2 -> Y|CDE|ABERT

Comment: You can order them by id: `group_concat(t2.name order by t2.id separator '|')`. But if you want them to be ordered according to `t1.ids` - that wouldn't be easy.

Comment: Is there ay method to get order by the each id of t1.ids?